# How to write variable with keyboard module in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying something. I wanna write variable with keyboard module but i didn't. Like this;

```
import keyboard

word = "hello"
keyboard.write(word)
```

Output: >>>hello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.write(word)
```